# Listview itemTemplate in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, listview, itemtemplate

I am having troubles getting the listview right of an ASP site. My data is as followed:

So I have a dictionary that contains a list of statistics:

```
Dictionary<string, IList<Stats>>

Data example:   Key                Value
               Port1               List<Stats>: - int NumberOfSuspended
                                           |    - int NumberOfCompleted
                                           |------ string messagetype
               Port2               List<Stats>: -int numberOfSuspendes
                                           |    - int numberOfCompleted 
                                           |-----string messagetype
```

The class "stats" contains a couple of variables (messagetype & numberofsuspended)

So I need to create a viewlist that looks like this:

```
<table>
 <tr><td>Port1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Messagetype</td><td>numberofSuspended</td>

 <tr><td>Port2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Messagetype</td><td>numberofSuspended</td>
  .......
 </table>
```

So basically: foreach List in Dictionary make a row with the stats properties (and the key of the dictionary is titlerow)

So end result is this:

```
|----------------------------------------------
| PORT 1
|----------------------------------------------
|   MessageType1:   |   0/0 |   0/0
|----------------------------------------------
|   MessageType2:   |   0/0 |   0/0
|----------------------------------------------
|-----------------------------------------------
| PORT 2
|----------------------------------------------
|----------------------------------------------
|   MessageType1:   |   0/0 |   0/0
|----------------------------------------------
|   MessageType2:   |   0/0 |   0/0
|----------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone help me with the itemTemplate of the listview?
I think it is a bit tricky because I make use of a dictionary?
I make use of DataBinding (Listview.Datasource = Dictionary<..>)

Thank you

Comment: You need to show the markup or the codebehind that is actually responsible for the binding. Another attempt would be to subscribe to the OnItemDataBound Event, to use e.Row.FindControl("") to get references to the asp.net elements of the current row and assign them the values there

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this theory, but let me know what you think:

Could you try adding a placeholder control, looping through each of the keys and applying the header in the loop, and also adding a repeater with the data from that respective key?

```
For each sKey as String in MyDictionary.Keys
  plcMyHolder.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<h1>" & sKey & "</h1>"))
  Dim rpt As New Repeater
  rpt.DataSource = MyDictionary(sKey)
  rpt.DataBind
  plcMyHolder.Controls.Add(rpt)
Next
```